# Get element array from array of struct

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a questions. 
Assume i have a structure

```
public struct submenu_str
{            
    public int mainMenNumber_int;
    public string menuText_str;            
    public int tag;          

  public submenu_str(int numb, string text, int Tag)
  {
        mainMenNumber_int = numb;
        menuText_str = text;
        tag = Tag;                
  }
}
```

I create an array of this structure

```
public submenu_str[] myActCmd = new submenu_str[3];
```

How do I of the array of the entire structure to get an array of only one element? If i want get an array of menuText_str from myActCmd array?

```
string strarray[] = myActCmd.menuText_str[] ?
```

How can i do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Select` (from LINQ) to map a collection of objects to a collection of a property of them. In your case:

```
string[] strArray = myActCmd.Select(a => a.menuText_str).ToArray();
```

Also, notating a variable with its type is not standard C# naming; nor should you be exposing a public field (use properties instead):

```
public string MenuText {get; set;}
```

would be more standard.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!